# Can a IOC Container replace CreateInstance reflection code?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a similar setup shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3940675/84539) and was wondering if I could replace all my code that uses reflection to find plugins of a certain type and then does a `CreateInstance` on it with a IOC Container that does something like:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MyType).Assembly)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do something like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MyType).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: What does the AsImplementedInterfaces do? The project has legacy code so will not have constructors with interfaces and will implement some interfaces concretely.

Comment: From the documentation of Autofac: *Specifies that a type from a scanned assembly is registered as providing all of its implemented interfaces.*

Comment: What if the class doesn't have interface constructors will they just be ignored? Just trying to minimalize impact!

Comment: @Jon - you could, in addition to `AsImplementedInterfaces`, add `.AsSelf()`. That way, the container will be able to resolve services both as any interface they implement as well as their concrete classes.